# Charger laptop disconnect after few minutes when laptop connect with monitor via HDMI

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, charger

I just bought new LG monitor of 24 inch. I connect it with my LENOVO laptop via HDMI cable. the problem is whenever I try to plug in my laptop charger, it will disconnect from charging even though the power is still on. I noticed this only happened when I connect my laptop to my monitor via HDMI. when I single charge the laptop without  plug in the HDMI cable, it works fine means the charging is normal and not disconnecting. can anyone explain the logic? at first I thought my extension socket was problem but it was not. I bought a new one but still failed. please help me.

Comment: Try a different HDMI cable

Comment: @Keltari is it because my HDMI cable stated there as "High Speed HDMI cable with Ethernet" ? I still remember I used to connect my laptop with other HDMI before and it works just fine. but maybe because this new HDMI cable is not compatible with my old laptop I guess.

Comment: @Keltari Hi Keltari. I tried different type of HDMI (the normal one) and also VGA but still failed. the laptop charger will disconnect after 1 minute-ish.

Comment: that is strange.  do you have a different monitor to try?